# How to get value from dropdown box for appending field

Tags: jquery, append

I want to get the value from a dropdown box. I can get the value of the first row
but not from the rows I add afterwards.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#combo').change(function(){
    alert( $('#combo').val());
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="combo">
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
  <option value="4">Test 4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="price_id"  name="price"/>
<a class="btn btn-default" id="add" href="#" role="button">Add entry</a> 

<div id="my_div">
</div>
 <script>
$( "#add" ).click(function() {
var newElement = '<select id="combo"><option value="1">Test 1</option> <option value="2">Test 2</option> <option value="3">Test 3</option><option value="4">Test 4</option></select> <input type="text" name="price"/> </br>';
$( "#my_div" ).append( newElement); 
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First you're using `id` which must be unique. You can use `class="combo"` instead and `".combo"` instead of `"#combo"` to select them. That is not enough I think because you're calling the `change` method before those elements exist. You have to call `change` on the new elements as you add them probably.

Comment: how can I call change on the new elements? i have changed it with class="combo" but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that your `$('#combo').change()` handler is run when the document is loaded, so elements created after that don't have the handler.

You can make that handler a function and then call it when you make new dropdowns.

The second issue is that you shouldn't make them all with the same ID.   So I changed all of the dropdowns to have `class="combo"`, instead of ID, and then made all of the handlers look for `$('.combo')`

When you're doing the `alert` inside the change handler, you can't refer to the value from the id anymore, but inside jQuery handler functions, `$(this)` refers to the element that triggered the event.  So `alert($(this).val())` alerts the value from the correct dropdown.

Finally, since we're repeatedly adding handlers, I shut the old ones off first, with `$('.combo').off('change').on('change', function(){`...  Otherwise, you would start getting multiple alerts from the dropdowns, because you would be adding (identical) handlers.

The snippet below is working

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
      setChangeHandlers()
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select class="combo">
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
  <option value="4">Test 4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="price_id"  name="price"/>
<a class="btn btn-default" id="add" href="#" role="button">Add entry</a> 

<div id="my_div">
</div>
<script>
    function setChangeHandlers() {
      $('.combo').off('change').on('change', function(){
        alert( $(this).val());
      });
    }
    $( "#add" ).click(function() {
      var newElement = '<select class="combo"><option value="1">Test 1</option> <option value="2">Test 2</option> <option value="3">Test 3</option><option value="4">Test 4</option></select> <input type="text" name="price"/> </br>';
      $( "#my_div" ).append( newElement); 
      setChangeHandlers();
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```